# .vue file not found in the coverage with istanbul, mocha and vue-test-utils in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, mocha.js, istanbul, vue-test-utils

I test my VueJS app with vue-test-utils. I would like to have a coverage. I use Istanbul to can have this coverage.
All .js files are displayed in the coverage, but no .vue file.

EDIT: `@Vue/cli` v.4.5.4 and the `Vue` v.2.6.12

my `nyc.config.js` file

```js
module.exports = {
  'check-coverage': false,
  'per-file': true,
  'skip-full': true,
  all: true,
  include: ['src/**/*.{js,vue}'],
  exclude: [
    'src/*.js',
    '**/index.js',
    'src/plugins/*',
  ],
  reporter: ['lcov', 'text', 'text-summary'],
  extension: ['.js', '.vue'],
}
```

my `babel.config.js` file

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset',
  ],
  env: {
    test: {
      plugins: [
        ['istanbul'],
      ],
    },
  },
}
```

my `package.json` file

```js
"scripts": {
    ...
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
    "test:unit:coverage": "nyc vue-cli-service test:unit",
    ...
  }
```

Comment: did you set up the project with Vue CLI 3?

Comment: @Vue/cli version is the 4.5.4 and the Vue version is the 2.6.12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you test a *.vue file, the directory of this file diplayed in the corevage list.

EDIT : or add

```
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') {
      config.merge({
        target: 'node',
        devtool: 'eval'
    }
  },
}
```

in your `vue.config.js`

source : https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils-mocha-webpack-example/issues/3